# Renaming Iframes with javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, rename

I am trying to figure out how to name/rename iframes with javascript.

```js
function sesamOpenU(){
  x = document.querySelector('iframe');
  x.style.height=  '200px';
  x.style.width= '400px';
  x.name = 'myFrame1' ;
  let url = 'https://www.example.com/'
  let other = window.open(url,'myFrame');
}
```

```html
    
<iframe name ="myFrame">
</iframe>
<button onclick= "sesamOpenU()">Sesam, open U</button>
```

First, i tried to name an iframe without a name with x.name after defining x.
no errors in the console, but no result either.

I named the iframe manually to target it, and it works.
Then I tried to rename it with Javascript, but again, no result.
For ruling things out, I decided to adjust the height and width for reference to see if it would adjust.
It does.

I tried the adjustments before the function, no result. (widht and heigh does, name doesn't)

Can someone shine a light on my problem?

Edit: yes, i know that i have targeted myFrame, and not myFrame1 in the example. It was the last step of testing which one it would take.  The named version, or the renamed version. The named version works, the renamed version doesn't ( opens the webpage in a new tab)
edit: solved.

Comment: It looks like a bug in Chrome. Firefox opens the url in the iframe if it has the same name as the browsing context used in `window.open`. Using the same code, however, Chrome opens it in a new tab. Can you test in Firefox to see if it produces the results you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing locally showed differences between Firefox and Chrome - Firefox happily opened the url supplied to `window.open` in the iframe with the same name as the browsing context supplied as the second argument. Chrome did not and would open the url in a new tab.

A possible workaround might be to set the `src` attribute of the iframe element directly:

```
function sesamOpenU(){
  x = document.querySelector('iframe');
  x.style.height=  '200px';
  x.style.width= '400px';
  x.name = 'myFrame1' ;
  let url = 'https://www.example.com/'
  // let other = window.open(url,'myFrame1');
  x.src = url;
}
```

This seems to work in both Firefox and Chrome, whether using `example.com` or the business site url provided in the original posted.

Comment: Apparently, this is the issue. 
I tested it in firefox. and it works just fine. 

When I saw it, it was a :" are you fn kidding me?!? " out loud response.

Answer (score 0):

The code does reassign the name of your iframe but the way you set the source does not seem to be working.

I tried the following which seem to be working:

```js
function sesamOpenU(){
  x = document.querySelector('iframe');
  x.style.height=  '200px';
  x.style.width= '400px';
  x.name = 'myFrame1' ;
  let url = 'https://www.example.com/';
  x.src = url;
}
```

```html
<iframe name ="myFrame">
</iframe>
<button onclick= "sesamOpenU()">Sesam, open U</button>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think they were trying to run the iframe in the current window (if they were, your solution would be fine) but they are trying to run it in an alternative window, hence the window.open rather than setting the iframe's src.

Comment: @AHaworth oh yeah maybe you are right. I was just thinking about what he wrote in his edit "It was the last step of testing which one it would take. The named version, or the renamed version. The named version works, the renamed version doesn't ( opens the webpage in a new tab)" which led me to believe that his preferred output was setting the src on the same page.

Comment: True, the intention was to run it in the iframe. Sorry for the miscommunication. It seems that it is a browser related issue. Chrome does rename the iframe, but still opens the link in a new tab. Firefox on the other hand executes it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Note: your code does not work in an SO snippet, at least on my system, it gives this error:

> js:26 Blocked opening 'https://www.alternate.nl/' in a new window
> because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups'
> permission is not set.

So I have tried it as a complete piece of code, see below.

It works fine with renaming the iframe - as long as you go back to having a url that will allow itself to be in a iframe - somehow your original url has been replaced by one that won't work - and whether or not the iframe had another name to begin with. Maybe there was some typo problem in the original code given which we missed? Anyway, all is well:

Here is the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name='myFrame'></iframe>
    <button onclick= "sesamOpenU()">Sesam, open U</button>
    <script>
    function sesamOpenU(){
      x = document.querySelector('iframe');
      x.style.height=  '200px';
      x.style.width= '400px';
      x.name = 'myFrame1' ;
      let url = 'https://www.alternate.nl/'
      let other = window.open(url,'myFrame1');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry,  Ill see to it next time that the snippet will be operational.
Apparently, it is a browser issue. Firefox executes the code as it should. Chrome adjusts the name, but still opens the webpage in a new tab. I was testing it in Chrome. Didn't come up to that it could be a browser issue.